# Equations for different quadrants of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

In the circle $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $a^2$, what's the general equation for the arcs in each of the quadrants?

Answer (score 1):

Different Quadrants of circle $$x^2+y^2=a^2$$ can be represented by 
$$y=\sqrt{a^2-(\sqrt {x})^4}$$
$$y=\sqrt{a^2-(\sqrt {-x})^4}$$
$$y=-\sqrt{a^2-(\sqrt {x})^4}$$
$$y=-\sqrt{a^2-(\sqrt {-x})^4}$$
I guess you've understood the trick

Comment: I don’t understand why you wrote $(\sqrt x)^4$ and $(\sqrt{-x})^4$ when in all cases these expressions boil down to $x^2$.

Comment: @Rubin I'm now going to have your upvote for this. Yes, that doesn't change the curve, it just adds a few restrictions on values of $y$ and $x$