# Locus of a point for only a certain range of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, locus

Good Day

I was solving to find the equation of the quadrant of a circle, when solving this:

> A ladder of length $l$ slides with its ends on positive $x$ and $y$ axis. Find the locus of the mid-point of the ladder.

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001671/equations-for-different-quadrants-of-a-circle), I was able to find the equation.

But, this made me wonder, what if I am given an equation and I want to make it valid for only some sections of $x$ values - that is, create custom "holes" in the graph.

For example, we can modify $$x = y$$ to $${(\sqrt{5 - x}} ^ 2 - (5 - x)) + ({\sqrt{x - 2}} ^ 2 - (x - 2)) + x = y$$ for $$2 \leq x \leq 5$$

How can we generalize this if I am given disjoint ranges $[l_1, r_1], [l_2, r_2], \cdots [l_n, r_n]$ or disjoint ranges $[l_1, r_1), [l_2, r_2), \cdots [l_n, r_n)$? For example, If I am given equation $$x = y$$ and I want a graph that exists only for $x$ values $[2, 5], [7, 9), (10, 11]$

Thanks

Comment: @MathMagician I don't get it. Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Does the question boil down to, "Is there a hack to avoid explicitly restricting a domain by using implicit restrictions from 'standard' functions?" <> And if so, is there a motivation beyond mathematical curiosity...?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the question is, but at one end when the ladder is vertical the midpoint is on the $y$ axis, while at the other end when the ladder is horizontal the midpoint is on the $x$ axis. The locus is a subset of the quarter circle in the first quadrant, which includes those two endpoints, and by continuity must include the complete arc between them, so there cannot be "holes" in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that you can use the fact that $(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a\lt b$ is non-negative if and only if $x\in(-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)$.

For example, for $[2,5],[7,9]$, one can have
$$\bigg(\sqrt{x-2}^2-(x-2)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{9-x}^2-(9-x)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{(x-5)(x-7)}^2-(x-5)(x-7)\bigg)+x=y$$

If you want to exclude $x=c$, then you can add $\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{x-c}-(x-c)$.

So, for $[2,5),[7,9)$ where $x=5,9$ are excluded, one can have
$$\bigg(\sqrt{x-2}^2-(x-2)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{9-x}^2-(9-x)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{(x-5)(x-7)}^2-(x-5)(x-7)\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{(x-5)^2}{x-5}-(x-5)\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{(x-9)^2}{x-9}-(x-9)\bigg)+x=y$$

Finally, for $[2, 5], [7, 9), (10, 11]$ which is your example, one can have
$$\bigg(\sqrt{x-2}^2-(x-2)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{11-x}^2-(11-x)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{(x-5)(x-7)}^2-(x-5)(x-7)\bigg)+\bigg(\sqrt{(x-9)(x-10)}^2-(x-9)(x-10)\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{(x-9)^2}{x-9}-(x-9)\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{(x-10)^2}{x-10}-(x-10)\bigg)+x=y$$

Comment: Thank You. Exactly what I wanted. We can also exclude $x = c$ by $\frac{1}{x-c} - \frac{1}{x-c}$ right? Thanks

Comment: @MangoPizza : You are welcome. Yes, we can.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric locus is the astroid, plane curve generated as envelope of straight lines.
(see:”A CATALOG OF SPECIAL PLANE CURVES”, J. DENNIS LAWRENCE, Dover Publications, Inc., New York.

Coordinates of the mid-point of the ladder are:

$x=\frac{l.cos(\alpha)}{2}$,

$y =\frac{l.sin(\alpha)}{2}$.

At each point of the ladder you have:

$\frac{x}{cos(\alpha)}+\frac{y}{sin(\alpha)}=l$.

Deriving this expression :

$x \frac{sin(\alpha)}{cos(\alpha)^{2}}-y\frac{cos(\alpha)}{sin(\alpha)^{2}}=0$.

From the system of the two equations we derive :

$x=l.cos(\alpha)^{3}$,

$y =l.sin(\alpha)^{3}$.

By eliminating $\alpha$, we get the equation of the geometric locus of the midpoint of the ladder:

$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=l^{\frac{2}{3}}$,

expanded

$\Big(x^{2}+y^{2}-l^{2}\Big)^{3}+27l^{2}x^{2}y^{2}=0$.

Comment: You are answering a different question than the one OP asked. The locus of the midpoint of a sliding ladder in the first quadrant is a quarter circle.